# Dock/Expose not working, Desktop stuck with gray background (Lion)

Tags: macos, dock, mission-control, expose

I am running Mac OS X 10.7.5 and the Dock/Mission Control/Desktop functionality is totally broken.  My dock is not present after startup so I have to start all applications from Spotlight.  I can't even alt-tab between them as the process that controls that function is also down.  My desktop is working but the background is permanently stuck on Gray no matter what I change it to.

`killall Dock` reports that there are no matching processes that belong to me.  I have removed the plist and db files for Dock and Desktop (`com.apple.{whatever}.plist`) in the Preferences folder and rebooted multiple times (both Safe Mode and regular) and nothing will change.  Does anyone know what might be wrong? Looking for a solution short of a full reinstall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luckily the computer was on 10.7 Lion so I had room to upgrade to 10.8 Mountain Lion which overwrote the corrupted Dock/Expose applications in the upgrade process.  My advice to anyone with a similar problem would be to upgrade OS X if possible or reinstall the current operating system if not (no need to delete user data).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and running `killall -KILL Dock` in terminal worked for me.